# 403 Forbidden in PATCH requests only in Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my Django App, suddenly `PATCH` requests suddenly stopped working and currently throwing only `403`. Moreover, `POST` requests are fine, and it is only malfunctioning in the production server.

Here are the configurations (very lax currently since I'm testing):

```py
"""
Django settings for bracitp project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

import environ

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
env = environ.Env(
    # set casting, default value
    DEBUG=(bool, False),
    PRODUCTION_DEBUG=(bool, False),
    SECRET_KEY=(
        str,
        "%76!9b2)1n60ntryvrsljdsldlasvs@q2$r4mmllwueawmt(zgdd",
    ),
    DB_HOST=(str, "db"),
    DB_PORT=(int, 5432),
    ALLOWED_HOSTS=(list, ["*"]),
    CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=(bool, True),
    CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=(list, []),
    ALLOWED_GOOGLE_AUTH_EMAIL_DOMAINS=(list, ["co.design"]),
    CACHE_BACKEND=(str, "redis"),
    CACHALOT_ENABLED=(bool, False),
    FILESYSTEM_LOGGING=(bool, False),
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=(bool, False),
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=(str, ""),
    BRAC_API_KEY=(str, ""),
)
# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env("SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = env("DEBUG")
PRODUCTION_DEBUG = env("PRODUCTION_DEBUG")
ALLOWED_HOSTS = env.list("ALLOWED_HOSTS")


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.postgres",
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount",
    "allauth.socialaccount.providers.google",
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework.authtoken",
    "django_filters",
    "dj_rest_auth",
    "dj_rest_auth.registration",
    "modeltranslation",
    "wagtail.contrib.forms",
    "wagtail.contrib.redirects",
    "wagtail.embeds",
    "wagtail.sites",
    "wagtail.users",
    "wagtail.snippets",
    "wagtail.documents",
    "wagtail.images",
    "wagtail.search",
    "wagtail.admin",
    "wagtail.core",
    "wagtail.contrib.modeladmin",
    "wagtail.contrib.settings",
    "wagtail.api.v2",
    "wagtailorderable",
    "wagtailmenus",
    "modelcluster",
    "taggit",
    "imagekit",
    "users",
    "courses",
    "enrollments",
    # "wagtail_modeltranslation",
    # "wagtail_modeltranslation.makemigrations",
    # "wagtail_modeltranslation.migrate",
    "cms",
    "private_storage",
    "rest_mediabrowser",
    "notifications",
    "corsheaders",
    "django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig",
    # "debug_toolbar",
    "cachalot",
]


DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = [
    "debug_toolbar.panels.versions.VersionsPanel",
    "debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerPanel",
    "debug_toolbar.panels.settings.SettingsPanel",
    "debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeadersPanel",
    "debug_toolbar.panels.request.RequestPanel",
    "debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel",
    "debug_toolbar.panels.staticfiles.StaticFilesPanel",
    "debug_toolbar.panels.templates.TemplatesPanel",
    "debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CachePanel",
    "debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalsPanel",
    "cachalot.panels.CachalotPanel",
]

CACHALOT_TIMEOUT = 3000


SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    # "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    #'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "bracitp.urls"

WAGTAIL_SITE_NAME = "BRACIPEDIA"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": ["bracitp/templates"],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "wagtail.contrib.settings.context_processors.settings",
                "wagtailmenus.context_processors.wagtailmenus",
            ]
        },
    }
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "bracitp/static")]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "bracitp.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": env("POSTGRES_DB"),
        "USER": env("POSTGRES_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": env("POSTGRES_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": env("DB_HOST"),
        "PORT": env("DB_PORT"),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator"
    },
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator"},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator"},
    {"NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator"},
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # 'users.models.UsernameOrEmailModelBackend',
    # "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    "LOGIN_SERIALIZER": "users.serializers.LoginSerializer",
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "Asia/Dhaka"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
        # "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",  # To keep the Browsable API
    ),
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ["rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated"],
    # "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": "rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination",
    "PAGE_SIZE": 50,
    "DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS": ("django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend",),
}


def gettext(s):
    return s


LANGUAGES = (("en", gettext("English")), ("bn", gettext("Bangla")))
MODELTRANSLATION_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = "bn"
MODELTRANSLATION_FALLBACK_LANGUAGES = ("bn", "en")

"""
   _____            _       _   _                 _
  / ____|          (_)     | | | |               (_)
 | (___   ___   ___ _  __ _| | | |     ___   __ _ _ _ __
  \___ \ / _ \ / __| |/ _` | | | |    / _ \ / _` | | '_ \
  ____) | (_) | (__| | (_| | | | |___| (_) | (_| | | | | |
 |_____/ \___/ \___|_|\__,_|_| |______\___/ \__, |_|_| |_|
                                             __/ |
                                            |___/
"""

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "google": {"SCOPE": ["profile", "email"], "AUTH_PARAMS": {"access_type": "online"}}
}


CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = env("CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS")

if not CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS:
    CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = env.list("CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS")
    CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = env.list("CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS")


# Django notifications
DJANGO_NOTIFICATIONS_CONFIG = {"USE_JSONFIELD": True}
DJANGO_NOTIFICATIONS_CONFIG = {"SOFT_DELETE": True}

FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644


EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "bracipedia@brac.net"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = env("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD")  # "Z@in1243"
EMAIL_PORT = 587


CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://redis:6379/0",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        },
    }
}


CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://redis:6379"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://redis:6379"
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ["application/json"]
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = "json"


# INTERNAL_IPS = type(str('c'), (), {'__contains__': lambda *a: True})()

REGISTER_DOMAINS = ["brac.net", "co.design"]

ALLOWED_GOOGLE_AUTH_EMAIL_DOMAINS = env("ALLOWED_GOOGLE_AUTH_EMAIL_DOMAINS")
# LfNL7rb5MN9HJyb

# SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'users.views.CustomSocialAccountAdapter'
# APPEND_SLASH = False

BRAC_API_KEY = env("BRAC_API_KEY")

if env("CACHE_BACKEND") == "redis":
    CACHES = {
        "default": {
            "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
            "LOCATION": "redis://redis:6379/0",
            "OPTIONS": {
                "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
            },
        }
    }
elif env("CACHE_BACKEND") == "locmemcache":
    CACHES = {
        "default": {
            "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache",
        }
    }

CACHALOT_ENABLED = env("CACHALOT_ENABLED")

if env("FILESYSTEM_LOGGING"):
    LOGGING = {
        "version": 1,
        "disable_existing_loggers": False,
        "handlers": {
            "console": {
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            },
            "logfile": {
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "class": "logging.FileHandler",
                "filename": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "log/logfile"),
            },
        },
        "root": {"level": "INFO", "handlers": ["console", "logfile"]},
    }

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = env("SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE")
```

And the environment variables:

```bash
DEBUG=True
PRODUCTION_DEBUG=True
CACHALOT_ENABLED=False
ALLOWED_HOSTS=bracipedia.brac.net
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=True
BRAC_API_KEY=2940094b-7a05-4860-8082-90a11967068d
```

Comment: Can you add the full error traceback/message and the view that raises the error?

Comment: @IainShelvington it doesn't raise any errors, even in debug mode.